# Android MANIFEST.MF equivalent

Tags: java, android, properties

On *normal* JVMs you can use `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` to declare application properties, in `J2ME` you can use the `.jad`-Files but what can you do on Android?

I need a way to declare properties which I can access using `System.getProperties()` on Android. It would be best if I could use the same file format as `MANIFEST.MF`-like property files use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html) would do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I usually put them in (for example) "res/values/props.xml"
Your build scripts can get at them, and then you just need to call: activityName.getString(R.props.propertyName); to pull out the value as a string.